# Hide icon of extension with Chrome 49

Tags: google-chrome-extension

It looks we can hide icon of extension for Chrome 48 and older. But after an update of Chrome to version 49 (dev channel), it displays my extension icon :(

I had neither "browser_action" nor "default_icon" in the manifest.json (witch is the tip for Chrome before version 49).

Any of you has the same issue ? How to get hidden the icon next to the address bar ?

Answer (score 11):

This is a (brain-dead if you ask me) [change by Chrome team](http://chrome.blogspot.ch/2016/01/new-year-new-chrome.html).

Even if you don't have a `browser_action`, your extension will display an icon (or failing that, a tile with extension name's first letter). If you do not declare a `browser_action`, it will be greyed out and non-interactive, but will still be there.

The idea is to alert the user that some potentially stealthy extension is installed. As such, only the user is empowered to hide the icon, by right-clicking and selecting "Hide in Chrome Menu".

I'm 100% positive this will result in user confusion, but there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I understand and, as end-user I agree the idea for security purpose. As developer, I'm annoyed because I would a discreet extension for well informed customers.

Comment: Install this extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/todotxt-lean-fast-task-ma/ohjgbfjncbnecbnijmpgjhodnhbhnjgk/related?hl=en - How did they do it? I don't see the icon in Chrome (48/49).

Comment: @Uri It's an app, not an extension. As such, it's in the App launcher, not the toolbar. Apps have very little potential of interfering with the browser, so I think Google wasn't concerned about them. On CWS you can tell if something is an extension if its details view has the icon inside a "puzzle piece".

Comment: @Uri Open a Store listing of an extension, say, Adblock. You'll see that it's icon in the top left is surrounded by a jigsaw piece shape. That's how you can tell in CWS. Locally, open the App Launcher - those listed here are apps.

Comment: I'm very sad to hear that :/

Comment: What happens when the `browser_action` section is removed. I removed that and the code (extension) did not work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844583/create-an-extension-for-chrome-to-just-run-a-background-script-without-user-inte